# Header animate on scroll in tablet Chrome issue

Tags: jquery, ios, google-chrome, ipad, jquery-mobile

I'm using [Tympanus animate on scroll plugin](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/06/on-scroll-animated-header/) to get my header shrink on scroll and it works great, the only issue that the plugin has is that even in it's demo, when you scroll on Chrome in tablet (Tested in iPad) it doesn't work until you fully stop scrolling, then the effect takes place.

Here's the jQuery:

```
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

    var docElem = document.documentElement,
        header = document.querySelector( '.navbar-default' ),
        didScroll = false,
        changeHeaderOn = 140;

    function init() {
        window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
            if( !didScroll ) {
                didScroll = true;
                setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
            }
        }, false );
    }

    function scrollPage() {
        var sy = scrollY();
        if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
            classie.add( header, 'navbar-shrink' );
        }
        else {
            classie.remove( header, 'navbar-shrink' );
        }
        didScroll = false;
    }

    function scrollY() {
        return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
    }

    init();

})();
```